# Facebook graph api /me (Android/iOS SDK) fails when using proxy

Tags: android, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, proxy

I tried to configure the android wifi proxy to send all traffic to a fiddler2 proxy. Then I tested the Facebook login function. The login is a success, but when I try to call graph api /me with the returned access token it fails. I assume it failed because I can't get the user id from the response. I can see some `https` packets going to `graph.facebook.com` in the fiddler2.

After I exclude `graph.facebook.com` from using proxy in the android wifi configuration. /me returned correctly with user id.

Same thing happened on the iPhone. But iPhone can't exclude domains from using the proxy. I'm stuck.

The login is success, and it goes to `https://m.facebook.com`. So are there any limitations on the facebook graph api?